# Use boolean condition in a TDE template context

Tags: marklogic

I need to generate one triple if one element<sup>1</sup> is present and its value as a boolean is `true`.  But the following test show the error I get when I try to use a sub-template with a context containing `[xs:boolean(.)]`:

```
tde.validate([xdmp.toJSON(
{ "template": {
    "context": "/foo",
    templates : [{
      "context": "bar[xs:boolean(.)]",
    }]
}})]);
```

I get the following error:

```
{"valid":false,
 "error":"XDMP-UNINDEXABLEPATH",
 "message":"XDMP-UNINDEXABLEPATH: Invalid syntax for path index: /foo/bar[xs:boolean(.)] "}
```

I use ML 9.2.  Any idea how to achieve such a condition in a TDE template?

---

<sup>1</sup> More precisely, one property of a JSON document, but that should not be relevant here.

Comment: TDE exposes only a limited subset of all functions, see http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE#id_99178. Did you try `fn:boolean` instead?

Comment: Thank you @grtjn.  The doc confirms the conversion function is indeed supported: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE#id_51421 (section "Type Casting").  `fn:boolean` is not exactly the same, but I've tried it anyway, and no, it does not pass either (same error message).

Comment: You are running 9.0-2, right? I am running 9.0-4, and your code snippet runs without errors in QConsole for me..